# Caching HTTP Get calls in SFMC for emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, json, ssjs

I've got a email which does a HTTP Get call using SSJS `Platform.Function.HTTPGet`, results return JSON and I can parse it successfully.
Would the calls get cached or would a Get call happen per subscriber? I need it to be cached.

I then came across this [Script.Util.HttpGet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformContentSyndicationScriptUtilHttpGet.htm)
 which should cache the get calls as per docs, however I can't use the parse JSON function as it results in an error.

> Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.  Line: 7 Char:
>   1  var json = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response.content)

Heres a simplified code snippet

```
 var req =  new Script.Util.HttpGet("https://api.myjson.com/bins/o9qvd");
 var response = req.send();
 var json = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response.content);
```

Any recommendations/suggestions, it seems like the get call is successful and I can print the results, but ParseJSON causes the issue

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what is returned? Perhaps the issue is inside the format or structure of your returned JSON or JSON string.

Comment: `Platform.Response.Write(typeof response.content)` returns `clr` (instead of `object`), so maybe there's something funky going on behind the scenes with `Script.Util.HttpGet`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you may need to convert `response.content` to a `String` first (initially it's `clr`; see my comment to your question, above):

```
var json = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(response.content));
Platform.Response.Write(json.name); // mkyong.com
```

Comment: I would use either HTTPGET (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformContentSyndicationHTTPGet.htm) or HTTP.GET from Core (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformContentSyndicationHTTPGet.htm) instead of the Util Get. I verifed both of these return the object from your endpoint as a string.

Comment: @Gortonington Can these cache content for use in mail sends the way `Script.Util.HttpGet` does? I think caching content was one of the asker's requirements. I remember a `Before;HTTPGet` from back in the day, but I haven't seen it used in a Content Builder.

Comment: It does not, but do note that if you are using in an email, in a comparison of the processing speeds, I have found that the fastest method is 1 - any GET from AMPscript (can then parse out via GTL) 2 - HTTPGET then HTTP.GET from SSJS and then 3 - any of the script.util (I believe these utilize a proxy server similar to WSProxy, but in this case it is less efficient as the calls need to take at least 4 steps (server to proxy to target to proxy) instead of 2 with the others (server to target).  Feel free to do your own comparison, might be different for you.

Comment: Also might make more sense to have the GET run via script activity and inserted into either your sendable or a relational DE (referenced with a lookup in email) prior to the send (via an automation) or at scheduled intervals rather than include SSJS inside the email. SSJS in email is not recommended at all.

Comment: The better way to go is the script activity to retrieve content before send and use GTL. I was initially using GTL but the actual JSON object is a lot more complex than the one I have given as a example here. It involves several levels of nesting, and from what I recall I ran into a few issues when trying to use data objects within different blocks of the email so resulted to SSJS instead. Thanks all for your help!